# If a module is an object from the class 'module' why aren't regular functions considered methods?

Tags: python

Begginer here trying to understand how python works and i came up with this doubt.

Shouldn't all functions be methods? Here's the code i used to verify this

my_module.py:

```
def func():
    pass
```

Main.py:

```
import inspect
import my_module

print(inspect.ismethod(my_module.func))
```

Output: False

Comment: `my_module.func` is not an _instance_ method.

Comment: I see, so inspect.ismethod returns True if it's an instance method, but my doubt still remains, is a regular function considered a method since it's from a module object?

Comment: I suppose that depends on your definition of "method".  I'm not sure if python itself makes a hard distinction between "function" and "method".

Comment: put `func` inside n class and in your main.py make an instance of that class and then try ismethod . importing a func from another module doesn't make an instance !

Comment: "A function that belongs to an object" since a module is an object, then all "regular functions" are methods? is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because methods are defined on the *class*. Any given module is an *instance* of the class module, not the definition of a new class.

Compare to:

```
class Foo:
    pass

f = Foo()
f.stuff = lambda: print('stuff')
```

`f.stuff` is an instance attribute of that particular instance of `Foo`, not of `Foo`s in general. The descriptor protocol (invoked when looking up an attribute on an instance, and finding it on the class, not the instance) is what converts functions on classes into methods of instances, and since these functions on a given module are all instance attributes of the module object, not the root class it's an instance of, no descriptor protocol is invoked, and the function doesn't become a method when called.

All that said, you *can* make subclasses of the `module` type, which would allow a module to have real methods. This is documented under [Customizing module attribute access](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-module-attribute-access) as a fallback in case the special methods they explicitly added support for (e.g. `__getattr__`, `__dir__`) aren't enough and you need your module to do other things. Since the `__class__` of a `module` is reassignable, you can reassign it to some other subclass of the `module` class and the methods of that class *will* receive `self` implicitly, so the same subclass can be assigned to multiple modules and provide per-module tailoring of behavior. For example:

```python
import sys
from types import ModuleType

class MethodModule(ModuleType):
    def dumb_method(self, x):
        return f"This is module named {self.__name__} which received {x!r}"

thismodule = sys.modules[__name__]
thismodule.__class__ = MethodModule

print(thismodule.dumb_method("foo"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NCsMgEITvPsXWUwIll94KfYTccitF0qgoxB/UtAklz241Sal725n5dscuQRh9iVEqa1wAv3jEnVEQFss8HGpr6DSyLkkIDWPvPbQscXTXq79dXxGkoYwDndSTqC1WeTbyM8yHm8exMDkNHHdCpjce1HYDdK8YhU8GGkLyRsgKbyEHkZiByVe255NbMUIhsQd3y82bffH3H/koIuncVp2QFC7rI2Sd1KEqomV3zI3BdR3jFw)

gives the module it's run within an instance method named `dumb_method` which customizes its behavior based on the `self` implicitly passed to it (in this case, using `self.__name__` to determine the name of the module).

Comment: Welp, time to add "setting `.__class__` of a module" to my list of things that I'll never accept in a code review. Neat trick!

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: It's actually explicitly documented, with an example, in the Data Model (see the link in the answer)! It's nuts! But it's totally legal. You can reassign `__class__` of most user-defined instances, so long as they have the same layout in memory (using `__slots__`, inheriting from a built-in type, and possibly using different metaclasses tends to make them incompatible). I'd definitely consider it the stinkiest code smell though.

Comment: I see, you made it really clear for me! thank you!! i'll give the way to having real methods on a module a try :)

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismethod) (emphasis mine)

> *inspect.ismethod(object)*
>
> Return `True` if the object is a **bound method** written in Python.

A *bound method* is a very specific type of object in Python. It's the result of [the `__get__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) on a function. If we have the class

```
class Cat:

    def speak(self):
        print("Meow")
```

Then `Cat.speak` is a function. It's an ordinary function with no magic applied to it.

```
>>> Cat.speak
<function Cat.speak at 0x7f835e7e44a0>
>>> inspect.ismethod(Cat.speak)
False
```

However, when we write `my_cat.speak` (where `my_cat` is a specific instance of the `Cat` class), *then* something magic happens.

```
>>> my_cat = Cat()
>>> my_cat.speak
<bound method Cat.speak of <__main__.Cat object at 0x7f835e7d7e10>>
>>> inspect.ismethod(my_cat.speak)
True
```

That's because, when we access something on an instance and that thing is *not* in the instance's `__dict__` (respectively, `__slots__`, for objects using that data model), then we look on the class itself. But when we look on the class for a name, we call `__get__` on that name. So `my_cat.speak` is actually equivalent to `Cat.speak.__get__(my_cat, Cat)`. That's not a hypothetical; we can actually write that in Python.

```
>>> Cat.speak.__get__(my_cat, Cat)
<bound method Cat.speak of <__main__.Cat object at 0x7f835e7d7e10>>
>>> inspect.ismethod(Cat.speak.__get__(my_cat, Cat))
True
```

So when we say something is a *bound method* in Python, we mean "someone took a function, chose a specific value for `self`, and returned a method object representing that binding". Module-level functions don't have a binding for `self`. `@staticmethod` functions don't have a binding for `self` (`@classmethod`s do actually; we just call it `cls` by convention). Anonymous lambdas and inner functions don't have a binding for `self`. `inspect.ismethod` is really just a typecheck against a "method" class. Again, this isn't hypothetical. This is [its implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cf6f23b0e3cdef33f23967cf954a2ca4d1fa6528/Lib/inspect.py#L299) in CPython right now:

> ```
> def ismethod(object):
>     """Return true if the object is an instance method."""
>     return isinstance(object, types.MethodType)
> ```

where [`types.MethodType`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/types.html#types.MethodType) is

> The type of methods of user-defined class instances.

---

Side note: Amusingly, `types.MethodType` is also [defined](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cf6f23b0e3cdef33f23967cf954a2ca4d1fa6528/Lib/types.py#L40) self-referentially

> ```
> class _C:
>     def _m(self): pass
> MethodType = type(_C()._m)
> ```

So, putting it all together, `inspect.ismethod` asks if the type of the object happens to match the type of `_C()._m`, where `_C` is a random class defined in the middle of the CPython implementation.